# Does lodash or vanilla JS have a nice way to flatten an object of arrays into an array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

What I want to do is take an object like

```
{  SomeKey: [A, B, C], 
   SomeOtherKey: [D], 
   AndAnother: [E, F]  }
```

and make it into

```
[ A, B, C, D, E, F ]
```

I don't see any nice way in [the documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.0), but maybe it's hiding in plain sight from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on the very latest generation of browsers, you may be able to use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), which does exactly what it sounds like:

```js
const data = {
  SomeKey: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  SomeOtherKey: ['D'],
  AndAnother: ['E', 'F']
};

const out = [].concat(...Object.values(data));

console.log(out);
```

If you're on slightly older browsers (back to IE9), [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is still pretty close:

```js
const data = {
  SomeKey: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  SomeOtherKey: ['D'],
  AndAnother: ['E', 'F']
};

const out = [].concat(...Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]));

console.log(out);
```

(`concat` optimization from [vlaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39581098/129032) edited in at [Oriol's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580898/does-lodash-or-vanilla-js-have-a-nice-way-to-flatten-an-object-of-arrays-into-an/39580935#comment66472263_39580935))

Comment: This creates too many intermediate arrays. Better use `[].concat.apply([], Object.values(data) )` or `[].concat(...Object.values(data))`

Answer (score 2):

## Using vanilla JS

```js
var input = {  
   SomeKey: ["A", "B", "C"], 
   SomeOtherKey: ["D"], 
   AndAnother: ["E", "F"]  
};

var outputES5 = Object.keys(input).reduce(function (memo, key) {
  return memo.concat(input[key])
}, []);

//Using ES6 fat arrow function
 const outputES6 = Object.keys(input).reduce(
  (memo, key) => memo.concat(input[key]),
   []
);

//Using Object.values and the spread syntax
const outputES6Values = [].concat(...Object.values(input));

console.log("ES5 reduce", outputES5);
console.log("ES6 reduce and fat arrow function", outputES6);
console.log("ES6 Object.values and spread syntax", outputES6Values);
```

[`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) - NOTE: this is not widely supported as of yet.

[Spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

## Using Lodash

```js
var input = {  
   SomeKey: ["A", "B", "C"], 
   SomeOtherKey: ["D"], 
   AndAnother: ["E", "F"]  
};

var output = _.flatMap(input);

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Using [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.0#flatMap) will iterate over all the *values* of the object since the default iteration function is simply [`_.identity()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.0#identity) and produce a single flattened array of all of them.

Comment: `concat(...arrayOfArrays)` is clever, I totally missed that optimization. +1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like lodash `_.flatMap` Does this.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.0#flatMap

```
var data = {
  SomeKey: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  SomeOtherKey: ['D'],
  AndAnother: ['E', 'F']
};

console.log(_.flatMap(data)); //["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gubs4tp0/)